# Issue with jena TDB (TDB.CreateDatase)

Tags: java, guice, jena, tdb

I'm trying to create a data base with TDB.CreateDataBase.

But I get an error that I can't spot. I put the stack trace bellow. Unfortunately there is some Guice involve which might make it difficult to catch. But I have pretty well isolated it and it is really an issue with TDB.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.interactionKB.InteractionKB.<init>(InteractionKB.java:200)
  while locating ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.interactionKB.InteractionKB

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1035)
    at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.osinfrastructure.OISInfrastructureService.start(OISInfrastructureService.java:138)
    at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.osinfrastructure.OISInfrastructureService.run(OISInfrastructureService.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB.initialization2(TDB.java:269)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB.<clinit>(TDB.java:264)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.setup.DatasetBuilderStd.<clinit>(DatasetBuilderStd.java:51)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.StoreConnection.make(StoreConnection.java:227)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction.DatasetGraphTransaction.<init>(DatasetGraphTransaction.java:75)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMaker._create(TDBMaker.java:57)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.sys.TDBMaker.createDatasetGraphTransaction(TDBMaker.java:45)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory._createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:104)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDatasetGraph(TDBFactory.java:73)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDataset(TDBFactory.java:52)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.createDataset(TDBFactory.java:48)
    at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.interactionKB.TripleStoreServiceIml.<init>(TripleStoreService.scala:61)
    at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.interactionKB.TripleStoreServiceIml$$FastClassByGuice$$f4f79dc3.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:88)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:279)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:996)
    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.invoke(FactoryProvider2.java:665)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.createTripleStoreService(Unknown Source)
    at ch.usi.ict.dev.ois.interactionKB.InteractionKB.<init>(InteractionKB.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:88)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:279)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1046)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:996)
```

Comment: What does your POM look like (or what dependencies are you including on your build path)?

Comment: Hi Joshua, i solved the issue, i mixed up some dependency in my sbt file. I have added, TDB and iri 1.1.0 as dependency while the rest of the component were 2.11.0.